# Targeting .NET 2.0 solution with SCSF-CAB

Tags: .net, scsf

My team is starting a new LOB WinForms app and I'm evaluating architectural solutions. We are able to develop with VS2008, but we have to target .NET 2.0. I'd like to use SCSF-CAB (April 2008), but the documentation says that .NET 3.5 is required to run (not just compile) apps built with this framework, and that is crux of my question:

Is .NET 3.5 truly a requirement for SCSF-CAB (April 2008)?

I ask this because I am able to recompile the Composite UI block and the SCSF Guidance Package, targeting .NET 2.0 in all projects, as well as pass all unit tests (except the 4 tests that are WPF-specific).

Could the compile/test cycle not reveal a .NET 3.5 dependency? Am I missing something about that requirement?

Update: I've created a basic Hello World module that runs inside an SCSF shell and it runs successfully on a virtual machine that has only Windows XP and .NET 2.0 SP2 on it. I also used Reflector to analyze some of the assemblies that ship with SCSF and the only dependency > .NET 2.0 that I've found is in assembly Microsoft.Practices.SmartClient.DisconnectedAgent (it references System.ServiceModel).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you stick to the core Microsoft.Practices.CompositeUI namespaces, you should be fine with .Net 2.0.